# Objective-C : Lowercase a NSString except the first char?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uppercase, lowercase

Is there an Obj-C function to uppercase the first char and lowercase the other ones ?

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes indeed:

```
[myString capitalizedString];
```

(Note that this will capitalize each word in a sentence (ie 'hello there' -> 'Hello There') aka 'Title Case')

Comment: I just realized it yes, luckily it's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @RobinDreux Glad to help you. If this is what you're looking for consider marking the answer as correct.